# PHP Weight Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, math, php4

I'm wondering if this is a sufficient algorithm for finding the best value with a weighted system. Is there anything I could add to make it better?

in this example I would like the probability of `$object->get()` returning test4 to be 4 times greater than the probability of it returning test1.

```
class weightCalculator { 
    var $data = array();
    var $universe = 0; 

    function add( $data, $probability ){ 
        $this->data[ $x = sizeof( $this->data ) ] = new stdClass; 
        $this->data[ $x ]->value = $data; 
        $this->universe += $this->data[ $x ]->probability = abs( $probability ); 
    } 

    function get(){ 
        if( !$this->universe ){
            return null; 
        }
        $x = round( mt_rand( 0, $this->universe ) ); 
        $max = 0;
        $i = 0; 

        while( $x > $max ){
            $max += $this->data[ $i++ ]->probability;
        }
        $val=-1;
        if($this->universe==1){
            $val = $this->data[$i]->value;      
          } else {
            $val = $this->data[$i-1]->value;                
        }
        return $val;
    } 
}

$object = new weightCalculator; 
$object->add( 'test1', 10 );
$object->add( 'test2', 20 ); 
$object->add( 'test3', 30 ); 
$object->add( 'test4', 40 );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "best value"? The assigned value for the random variable $x, based on the ordered weights of all data items in this->universe?

Comment: I guess i'm wondering if the method I'm using is the best way to calculate the weighted value of a result.

Comment: Ask a silly question, but what are you trying to do here?

Comment: pass in values, with weights, and have it return me with 1 result factoring in the weights of the values i've passed in.

Cheers

Comment: So in this example you'd like the probability of $object->get() returning test4 to be 4 times greater than the probability of it returning test1?

Comment: In your example, you get into trouble if mt_rand returns 100, don't you?  I think the max there needs to be $this->universe - 1.  I think that also eliminates the need for the $this->universe == 1 special case, if I understand correctly why it's there.

As for improvements -- one question I have is if you want to optimize for memory or speed?  This will be slow for a large number of objects.

Comment: Looking to optimize for speed mostly. Yea I was worried it could be costly for a larger data sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on streetpc's answer; alongside your data array, use `add()` to maintain a same-sized keys array where you store the upper bound on your range; for your example, that array would look like {10, 30, 60, 100}.  (Or, use one array containing objects or structs that contain both the data and the key.)  Then, your `get()` method is simply searching a sorted list for the first element greater than `$x`; a binary search could do that in O(ln N), compared to O(N) for your method.  You'll chew up a little extra memory -- but for most applications, it looks like a good tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

Seems fair enough, depends on the use. If you need better performance for the `get()` method, you could build your range values in the `add()` method and use dichotomy.